# Setting bottom margin of a view in code has no effect

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-xml

I'm having trouble setting the margins for an imageview in code. Trying to set the ivSmall image to have the same bottom and right margin, the right sets but the image still aligns to the dead bottom of the relative parent layout

```
 <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutImages"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivBig"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivSmall"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:background="@color/border_grey"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:padding="1dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have to figure out the size of the image in code so any layout params I set in XML will get overridden

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(mapHeight, mapHeight);

params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
params.setMargins(0, 0, mapOffset, mapOffset);
viewHolder.ivSmall.setLayoutParams(params);
```

the variable mapOffset is an dp to px integer. It is not null and positive, I can set it to something arbitrary too and the right margin will always set but still stays at the bottom of the parent.

[image]

Comment: Please tell me how the view should appear interms of diagram

Answer (score -1):

why not

```
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM|RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
```

Comment: The problem isn't it aligning to parent bottom and right its that the bottom margin is ignored. i think its a bug